# How do I get the url for attachments on an SPListItem using C#?

Tags: development, splistitem

I have an SPListItem for which I would like to get the urls of all its attachments.  The urls will be used as part of my custom web part which has an SPList of SPListItem items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAttachmentUrls(SPListItem item)
{
  return from string fileName in item.Attachments
         orderby fileName
         select SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Always use SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl to combine urls

Comment: Doesn't this return an `IEnumerable<string>`, though. I think `string[]` as the return type might not work...

Comment: @RobertKaucher You would be correct.  I think that I forgot to add in the parentheses and the .ToList() when I originally wrote this example.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following code in an itemAdded event receiver.

```
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            if (properties.ListTitle == "Architecture Calendar")
            {

                base.ItemAdded(properties);
                string eventUrl = null;
                string AttachUrl=null;

                using (SPSite site = properties.OpenSite())
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SPList listCalendar = web.Lists[properties.ListId];
                            SPItem itemCalendar = properties.ListItem;
                            SPSite mainSite = new SPSite(site.Url + @"/admin/");
                            SPWeb mainWeb = mainSite.OpenWeb();

                            **AttachUrl = properties.ListItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + properties.ListItem.Attachments[0];**

                            SPList listIntegrated = mainWeb.Lists["IntegratedEvents"];
                            SPListItem itemIntegrated = listIntegrated.Items.Add();

                            **itemIntegrated["Picture"] = AttachUrl;**



                            itemIntegrated.Update();


                        }
                        catch (Exception Ex)
                        {
                            throw Ex;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```