# Repeater display attachment

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

**new SPAttachmentCollection** is getting red what the problem?
Want to display an attachment in Repeater

```
<%# (new SPAttachmentCollection(((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Attachments"].ToString()).UrlPrefix) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Morski,

Instead can you try the following:

```
<%# (((SPListItem)Container.DataItem).Attachments.UrlPrefix) %>
```

UrlPrefix property will give you only the Url Prefix part for the Attachments, you need to append the attachment file name to make complete Attachment Url...

Please follow below link:
[How do I get the url for attachments on an SPListItem using C#?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32077/how-do-i-get-the-url-for-attachments-on-an-splistitem-using-c)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! but i get this following error on my site http://wingtip:49074/Lists/News-ListInstance1/Attachments/1/ and not the attachment?

Comment: @MorskiMartin I have updated the answer!

Comment: Hi i have tryed with this code,but dont get it to work 'private IEnumerable<string> GetAttachmentUrls(SPListItem item)
{
  return from string fileName in item.Attachments
         orderby fileName
         select SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix, fileName);
}

'

Comment: Do it on Item databound event, instead of page file...