# Listinstance url

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I'm working to show my attachments in a repeater control. It works ALMOST perfectly. I just want to get the full url to my attachment. Right now i'm getting: `http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News/Lists/KnowIT.News-ListInstance1/Attachments/1/` but i want it to show `http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News/Lists/KnowIT.News-ListInstance1/Attachments/1/banana.jpg`

The aspx code i'm currently using is:

```
<a href="<%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem).Attachments.UrlPrefix %> " target="_blank"><%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem).Attachments[0] %></a>
```

This is my buttonclick event code:

```
    protected void ButtonChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News"))
            {
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListCategory2.SelectedItem.Value);

                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
                query.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true;
                query.RowLimit = 3;

                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

                RepeaterContent.DataSource = items;
                RepeaterContent.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            LabelException.Text = LabelException.Text =  "";
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are can be several attachments. I think that you can use second repeater in your fist repeater to show all attachments. How to get correct URLs for the attachments you can see in this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32077/how-do-i-get-the-url-for-attachments-on-an-splistitem-using-c).