# How to retrive Image URL from Custom List,in sandbox solution using Visual studio(C#)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I'm trying to retrieve image/attachment url from custom list, while I am fetching image url and passing to **img tag** then it returns true rather Image URL,like `src="true"` and i want it like  `src="http://abc.png"`

```
    private const string TitleColumn = "Title";        
    private const string Attchment = "Attachments";
    var webUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;

    using (var site = new SPSite(webUrl))
    {
        using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                var List = web.Lists["SimpleList"];
                var spQuery = new SPQuery
                {
                    Query = "</Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=" + TitleColumn + "/><FieldRef Name=" + Attchment + "/>"
                };

                var Items = List.GetItems(spQuery);
                if (Items != null && Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItem item in Items)
                    { 
                        var ImageLink = new SPFieldUrlValue(item[Attchment].ToString());
                        imageTag.Attributes.Add("src", ImageLink.Url);                        
                        imageDiv.Controls.Add(imageTag);//image added to image div
                    }
                }
             }
            catch (Exception ex)  {   }                  
        }
    }
```

This approach works SSOM. How can I get the image url in sandbox solution SharePoint online CSOM?

Comment: It should work in the sandboxed solution as well! What's your field name? if it is `Attchment`, then put it like `new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Attchment"].ToString());`

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below method as detailed by [skeletank](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/32080/1806):

> ```
> private IEnumerable<string> GetAttachmentUrls(SPListItem item)
> {
>   return from string fileName in item.Attachments
>          orderby fileName
>          select SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix, fileName);
> }
> ```

Comment: how do i implement this with the above mensioned approch?means m not undesrstnding,how to pass that specific value to this function.

Comment: As per my understand, You have attached images to list item so Pass the list item object in this method and it will return the attachment urls.

Comment: You can change return type of this method to string array as per your need

Comment: like this? GetAttachmentUrls(item);

Comment: yes...pass the sharepoint list iten object

Comment: Can you give the reference from where you copied? I think it is: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/32080/21421 @DikeshGandhi